# Setting keypool size in the conf file

Tags: bitcoin.conf, keypool

I used keypool=10000 in the conf file but bitcoin-cli -getinfo shows "keypoolsize":1000. Why?

Comment: Try running `keypoolrefill`

Comment: But that will just refill it back to 1000 in case I use a couple of addresses and bring it down to 998, right? I need the size to be expanded.

Comment: This sort of thing is almost totally irrelevant with HD wallets.

Answer (score 2):

`keypoolsize` only shows how many keys are currently in the keypool. It does not reflect the maximum size of the keypool. The `keypool=<n>` option does not automatically fill the keypool to that size, you will need to refill it by using `keypoolrefill`.

If after `keypoolrefill` you still do not see a larger keypool, then that means your bitcoin.conf file is either named incorrectly, located in the wrong location, or formatted incorrectly.